# Storing instanced variables in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I wrote a plugin to validate forms across the network where i work. The problem here is that some of our pages have multiple forms and the global variables get overwritten. I'll try to give an example as best i can. The code itself would be too long to paste.

I know this code is horribly wrong but i'm trying to gauge the best way to achieve using multiple instances of this code without making things too complicated.

jquery plugin:

```
(function($){

    methods = { 
        'method1': function(){
            alert('form: ' + globals.form_name ); 
        }
    }

    $.fn.validationplugin = function() {
        globals.form_id = $(this).attr('id');
    }(jQuery);

    var globals = {}


}(jQuery);
```

html calls:

```
<form id="form1"></form>
<form id="form2"></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#form1').validationplugin();
    $('#form2').validationplugin();
</script>
```

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are doing inside the plugin, but it might be as simple as creating the `globals` variable inside the function to make it local (though you might want to change the name then ;)). What is the object for anyway? Everything that is specific to an element has to happen inside the function, and even better, inside the `this.each()` callback inside your function (which you currently don't have).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array for the form identities:

```
var globals = {
  form_id: []
};
```

The plugin can be called with a single element or several elements, so you have to get the identities for each element. Also return `this` from the function so that the plugin can be chained. Also, you don't want `(jQuery)` at the end, as that will call the function and assign the return value as the plugin:

```
$.fn.validationplugin = function() {
  return this.each(function(i, el){
    globals.form_id.push($(el).attr('id'));
  });
};
```

Now it also works when there is more than one element in the call:

```
$('#form1,#form2').validationplugin();
```

Consider if you can use the reference to the elements instead of their identity, then it would work for a form without an identity also.

Comment: this solution would work except i'm passing different variables into each function call. I sort of ended up doing something similar tho.

Comment: @v3xx3d: It works just fine with separate calls also. You just should build your plugin so that it works with either single or multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this...

```
$.fn.validate = function(){

    var formnametest = $(this).attr('id');

    if( !($.validate.globals[ formnametest ]) ){
        globals(formnametest);
    }
}

function globals(formnametemp){
    $.validate.globals[ formnametemp ]  = {
        'mobile': false,
        'mobileoffset': -115,
        'bubbleanimationtime': 500,
        'bindblur': true,
        'zindex': null
    }
}

$.validate = { 
    globals:{}
};
```

I created a function globals() that would add a new instance of my default global variables and give it the same name as the form. Only consequence was i had to pass the name of the current form through all my functions, which i was trying to avoid but it's all good. Thanks @Guffa, your input helped me put things into perspective.

To refer to any of these global variables later it was simply:
$.validate.globals[ currentform ].propertynamehere

seems long-winded but it was exactly the result i needed. :)

Comment: feel free to critique. i'm still a noob.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming that you will be calling your plugin against the same element more than once, and want to associate data between those calls. If that is not the case, then you really don't need "globals" at all. As @Felix Kling says in the comment, just use a local variable instead.

But if you need to keep track of data that can be persisted between more than one call to the plugin, you can do it like this:

```
(function($){

    var globals=[],
        instances=[];

    $.fn.validationplugin = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            var current,
                index = $.inArray(this,instances));

            if (index!==-1) {
                current = globals[index];
            } else {
                instances.push(this);
                current = {};
                globals.push(current);
            }
            current.form_id = $(this).attr('id');
            ... 
        }
    };
}(jQuery);
```

This will cache an object associated with each DOM element passed to the plugin. If a subsequent call is made to the plugin on the same element, the same global object will be used on that subsequent call.

You can also just use jquery `data` to associate data with any DOM element, though it may be less efficient than caching it yourself.